# Does the wildchild Wild Rumpus table totally supersede the Feral Child table or are parts merged?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-classics-rpg, umerica

In the *Umerican Survival Guide*, page 60, there's a table (C5) for the Feral Child as is common for all classes in Umerica and in standard DCC.  Additionally on page 61, there's a table (C6) for the Wild Rumpus, an ability gained by one of the 3 factions of wild children.

Does the stuff on the Wild Rumpus table totally supersede the normal Feral Child table? Or do parts combine?

I am confident that some of the stuff supersedes, because having 2 crit die/table values makes no sense.  Also, the rules note you cannot use luck when on a rumpus.

However, the rest is unclear, such as the points below (examples, not a full list):

- Can I sneak attack as a Feral Child when on Wild Rumpus?
- Do I gain my attack bonus as a Feral Child in addition to my beast die when attacking in a rumpus? Or *just* the beast die?
- Are my Wild Rumpus saves in addition to the Feral Child saves or replacing them?

If you believe the answer is "it depends" and this blocks you from answering, let me know in a comment and I can more fully list all the questions/grey areas I believe they are.  I was trying to avoid making 1 question with what was really multiple questions.

I intend to ask my GM, so am really looking for citations or quotes I missed, vs "my group does..." or "I would...".

(I understand there's a new release of the guide either coming out or recently released.  Mine says Copyright 2017.  I don't see how to tell what edition it is otherwise – but am happy to provide that information with guidance.)